# Play last "N" images as a movie

Tags: php, image, animation

I have created a php script to fetch images from a certain URL at specified time intervals say, 5 minutes into a folder. I wish to play the same as a movie/animated GIF, whichever is possible and then embed the same in iframe. Kindly share the simplest code, as I tried to find, but all I found required manually providing the image url(s), what I want is to specify the folder and last "n" number of images to be played.

Thanks,
Nix.

Comment: You need to show more research effort to get help here.  Have a look at using the imagemagick API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417762/make-an-animated-gif-with-phps-imagemagick-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use image magick to combine the images to an animated gif. Here is explained how: http://blog.gotofritz.net/geekery/combining-images-imagemagick/ (halfway down the page), but you should consult http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php too.

ImageMagick is installed on most Webspaces.

You will probably need to generate the list of files to use in php (saving them with numbers in the file name could help, or you could use the time stamp of the file) or delete old images.

Comment: Thanks Jost, the script I have made renames the fetched image to current time and date. Will that be useful in this scenario too?

Comment: Of course - read the list of the files in the directory, and sort them by date (I assume sorting them will do the right thing in your naming-scheme). Then take the last (or first, whichever is appropriate) N filenames and give them to ImageMagick in your input.