# Make the horse look like it's running- JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a folder full of images. Each image is of a horse running in sequence. I want to give the user the allusion that horse is running by displaying the images sequentially and quickly.

Can any one suggest a good library or approach to achieve the above

Comment: You can create an animated gif. Serverside: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417762/make-an-animated-gif-with-phps-imagemagick-api

Comment: You should just google for that.  This site is for helping with specific code problems, not writing it or suggesting libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked this question and tagged it javascript and jquery, but since you asked what the best approach is:

The best approach would be to make the images into a sprite sheet (ie. one combined image) and use this sheet with proper background-position on an element. By using CSS3 animation in steps you can change the background-position, giving the illusion of the image moving.

So, don't use *n* amount of images, use a single image where you have combined all frames.

Say that each frame is 100x100 px, and you have 10 frames. That would give you a sprite sheet of 100*1000 px. Set this images as the background on an element:

```
.running-horse {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(sprite.jpg) top left;

  animation: runningHorse 1s steps(10) infinite;
}

@keyframes runningHorse {
  to {
    background-position: -1000px;
  }
}
```

`steps(10)` in the animation property is what makes it *jump* to the next image, instead of sliding the sprite sheet.

Read more about [step based CSS3 animation](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps)