# ImageMagick animated GIF compression

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have the following code to generate an animated GIF from a list of images. It's working fine but I would like to compress it. I tried a lot of different strategies but the resulting size is always **exactly** the same.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

class GifCreator
{
    public function createGifFromImages(array $images)
    {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/10095594
        $gif = new \Imagick();
        $gif->setFormat("gif");

        // adds all the images
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $frame = new \Imagick();
            $frame->readImage($image->getRealPath());
            // THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES ARE NOT WORKING
            //$frame->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
            //$frame->setImageCompressionQuality(5);
            $frame->setImageDelay(50);

            $gif->addImage($frame);
        }

        // optimizes the GIF
        $gif->optimizeImageLayers();

        // https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/Imagick/optimizeImageLayers/php-imagick-optimizeimagelayers-method-examples.html
        // THE FOLLOWING 2 LINES ARE NOT WORKING
        //$gif->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_LZW);
        //$gif->setImageCompressionQuality(30);

        // writes the GIF
        $tempPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'GIF');
        $result = $gif->writeImages($tempPath, true); 

        return $tempPath;
    }
}
```

It seems that `addImage` isn't applying the proper filters.

Comment: The GIF format doesn't support JPEG compression or LZW compression, so you should not expect them to make a difference. One of the few optimisations available is to create a palette of shared, common colours across frames - and that is what `optimizeImageLayers()` does.

Comment: Depending on the content, you could try reducing colours. Try something drastic like 31 colours or 63 colours to see if it helps and if it is acceptable.

Comment: @MarkSetchell but why can't I optimize jpeg images before adding them to the GIF using `$gif->addImage($frame);`? How can I reduce colors? Thanks.

Comment: JPEG compression only happens when IM actually **writes** a JPEG image to a file or an output stream. In your case, it doesn't do that, it just attaches a copy of the memory buffer with the pixel data in it onto a list of images.

Comment: You can reduce colours with http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.quantizeimage.php